# Usage Analytics Event Store not updating - Popularity Reports showing 0 - Delete Usage Receivers

Tags: site-usage, analytics

I'm having troubles getting the popularity reports to show any information, they only show 0's for all days.

I've narrowed the problem down to the Event Store files not being created. I can see the .usage files being created and disappearing in the Request Usage folder but no  recent dated folders in the Event Store. There are 3 folders for 5/20- 5/22 but nothing in Popularity reports for those days.

Other items of information:

- The request usage db on the SQL server are also empty
- Usage Data Import & Usage Data Processing jobs succeed
- Running the command below does show some data that does look correct and the last time it processed was the date of the last Event Store folder:
  [image]

I can also see the Analytics and Page Requests receivers are online. I've seen a lot of posts where these receivers were disabled and gave instructions to re-enable. Does anyone know how to safely remove these receivers and add them again? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

To remove the event receivers you need to call .Delete() method.

```
$ad.Receivers.Delete()
```

I have tried the reassignment of event receivers but still analytics folder is not getting updated with recent usage data.

Please let me know if anyone has solved this problem.

FYI
- We faced same issue on test server, i tried deleting and recreating search service application which has resolved this issue on test server, but that is something i don't want to try with a production environment

Answer (score -1):

Refer: [SharePoint 2013 – Usage Analytics (the story)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spblog/archive/2014/04/03/sharepoint-2013-usage-analytics-the-story.aspx)

Try checking receiver as mentioned in it

To remove you can try -

```
$ad.EnableReceivers = $false
```

Then

```
$ad.Receivers.Add("Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Applications, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c","Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Analytics.Internal.AnalyticsCustomRequestUsageReceiver")
```

and then enable as mentioned in article